# Fetch Map value from session inside Struts JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a session variable(it is a `map` with the structure `Map<String,ArrayList<String>>)` in JSP.
When i print the value in the console like 
`<%System.out.println("Session Value "+session.getAttribute("PRODUCTTYPESTEMP"));%>` it is printing the entire value in the console.
All I want is to get the `ArrayList` value by passing the desired `key` and get it printed with `check box`. 
I am not sure how to do this. 
BTW I am not familiar with `struts` or `JSP`.
Any help is much appreciated.

For reference, Below is the existing piece of code(please ignore , if its confusing, please provide a way to achieve the above mentioned functionality ) - Which will work if the `session` returns `ArrayList` , I am trying to rewrite it for `map` by passing desired `key`.

```js
<input type="checkbox" id="warrantsCb2"/><span></span></label><label for="warrantsCb" style="font-size:12px"><b>Warrants</b></label>
     <ul class="nested">
     <li>
      <label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label>Warrants
     </li>
     <% colCntr=0; %>       
     <s:iterator var="product_types"  value="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']">
     <li>
     <label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="productTypeCodesTemp" name="productTypeCodesTemp" value="<s:property value="#product_types_temp.value"/>"
     <s:iterator var="productTypeTemp" value="#attr['productTypeCodesTemp']">
     <s:if test="%{#attr['productType']==#product_types.value}"> checked="checked" </s:if> 
     </s:iterator>/>
     <span></span></label>
      <s:property value="#product_types.label"/> 
     </li>
     </s:iterator>
     </ul>
```

Edit -
Added new code with the help of Madis R

```js
<li class="caret">
 <input type="checkbox" id="warrantsCb" checked="checked" /><label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="warrantsCb2"/><span></span></label><label for="warrantsCb" style="font-size:12px"><b>Warrants</b></label>
 <s:iterator value="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']"> 
    <s:property value="Baskets"/> 
    <s:checkboxlist name="checkboxes" list="value"/> 
 </s:iterator>
</li>
```

The above is printing all the values with check boxes. 
I need to pick only the `ArrayList` values associated with the `key` "Baskets"

Edit:
After implementing the latest solution , value is being fetched but check boxes are not available. I should align **Warrant** like **'Unknown'** in the screen shot and the code

```js
<td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding:0">
 <div class="acidjs-css3-treeview">
     <ul>
   <li class="caret">
   <input type="checkbox" id="warrantsCb" checked="checked" /><label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="warrantsCb2"/><span></span></label><label for="warrantsCb" style="font-size:12px"><b>Warrants</b></label>
    <s:checkboxlist name="checkboxes" list="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']['Baskets']"/>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that i understand you but in struts 2 you can access session by implementing interface `SessionAware` in your action or getting it from ActionContext `ActionContext.getContext().getSession()`. There is no need to write java code directly into jsp

To get data from session you can try this in your jsp:

```
<s:iterator value="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']['Baskets']"> // iterates over list with map key Baskets
    <div>
        <s:property/> // gets element from Baskets
    </div>
</s:iterator>
```

EDIT:
Try this, it gets list from map with key Baskets and creates checkboxes with values:
`<s:checkboxlist name="checkboxes" list="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']['Baskets']"/>`

Comment: Hi Madis, I modified the 9th line like you mentioned , Now I get 3 check boxes but no values, the 3 count is correct because the basket key has 3 values.Still checking how to get the value. Thank you Madis, that was a great improvement.

Comment: I am completly lost here. Can you put the collection that you are trying to iterate over (for example `Map<String, List<String>>`) and what kind of data you want to display. I also dont understand what is `product_types_temp`, maybe this should be `product_types`. Also what is `#attr` that you are using.

Comment: Actually those are some existing code. I changed the `product_types_temp` to `product_types` still its showing `null`

Comment: Will try this and let you know, Thank you

Comment: Did you use my example exacly and used s:checkboxlist? I tested and it worked. Can you show what code did you use?

Comment: I tried like this

`<s:iterator value="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']['Baskets']"> 
             <!--   <s:property value="Baskets"/> -->
              <s:checkboxlist name="checkboxes" list="value"/> 
          </s:iterator>` but in the page only where it displays the check box , I could see this line `Error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed. 
`

Comment: Madis, Now there is a great improvement. except the checkbox and some format issues. I have pasted the screen shot in the question. I am also trying some fix meanwhile

Comment: I am accepting your answer, since the original question is answered.

Comment: Madis, Thanks ... 
Now, I could fetch all the values , but the check boxes are not appering. I have pasted the screen shot

Comment: It is very hard to say what could be the problem just by looking at the image.

Comment: I am afraid i am unable to help you. I took your code sample and every checkbox was displayed for me.

Comment: No Problem Madis R
Thanks a lot for your Help

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the exact code, which is working for my requirement here, 
Hope this will help some poor souls out there.
This is based on the solution provided by Madis R

```js
<ul class="nested">
 <s:iterator value="#session['PRODUCTTYPESTEMP']['Certificates']">       
           <%--Certificates is the key we are passing into the map--%>        
 <li> 
        <label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><s:property/>                   
 </li>          
 </s:iterator>
 </ul>
```

Comment: If anyone can add any improvement ... pls do. Since this solution is purely based on trial and error.